# Compiling individual .scss files with compass command line

Tags: node.js, sass, compass-sass, gruntjs

Is there a way through the compass command line utility to compile individually files?

The reason I am asking is that I currently have a grunt tasks that runs the compass compile command for the directory however this is probably going to be a problem when the project get bigger and it try to compile dozen of files when one one file changes so I am trying to see if there is a way to do something like compass compile app/css/style.scss:app/css/style.css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I needed to add project_path to my config.rb file.